# ?rel=0 auto changes to %3Frel%3D0 when adding to end of YouTube link to stop related videos… Why?

Tags: facebook, youtube, video-streaming

Sometimes on Facebook when I add the `?rel=0` to the end of a YouTube link to disable the related videos from showing at end of video, it automatically change that `?rel=0` to `%3Frel%3D0` once I click *Done Editing?* Why does it do this sometimes and not others? What does `%3Frel%3D0` do differently than `?rel=0` does? Or do those two do the same thing?

Also, can you add *both* `&fmt=18` and `?rel=0` to the end of a YouTube link on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

`%3Frel%3D0` is just the URL encoded version of `?rel=0`

You can check it [here](http://www.url-encode-decode.com). And can read more about URL encoding [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Why this happens only sometimes and not some other times, I don’t know, but is exactly the same thing.

And I think the `fmt` parameter is deprecated, which means most likely it will not work.